# Upgrade of package deletes some necessary EXE and DLL files (MSI FACTORY)

Tags: windows-installer, factory

I've built a complex installer via Msi factory 2, which uses some merge modules.
The problem is, after I try to "Upgrade" - I mean to install the package above an old one (Changed the product GUID and the product version), I discover that some exe or dll files that were suppose to be present in the install directory are missing, looks like they've been deleted, and haven't been replaced by newer files...

Any ideas what may have happened?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: It happens in more than one MSI Installer. It deletes the old files but doesn't install the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've broken the [Component Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For more info, check out [Component Rules 101](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/10/18/Component-Rules-101) and [Paying for Upgrades](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/12/30/paying-for-upgrades/) - if you think you've broken the component rules, then schedule `RemoveExistingProducts` *early* instead of late (late is more efficient, but if you break the component rules then you get errors like yours).

> InstallInitialize action.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Windows Installer which cases this behavior. You have to increase the version for the files that don't get installed.